# BlacK Hole from Space Station

Tags: gravity, black-holes

It's 80 years in the future and my colleague and I are working on the exterior of our Space Station located far outside the Solar System.

For whatever reason - he is envious of my recent work or wants the cornflakes all to himself he frees my safety attachment and pushes me off into space while my back is turned.

By sheer co-incidence he pushes me towards a black-hole and my trajectory is aimed right at the singularity from the start. I am very far away though and beyond the original star's gravity radius for several days.

At what point does my trajectory become altered by the curvature?

Since I am aimed at the singularity from afar will I travel in a constant straight line?

Comment: Why is it important that it is exactly 80 years in the future, and why shouldn't your trajectory depend on the curvature from the start?

Comment: What do you mean by "gravity radius"? The range of gravity is infinite. Also, if it only takes a few days of freefall to reach the BH, it's *very* close.

Comment: @PM2Ring - I'm trying to say that I'm starting from a position where I am not affected by the black hole gravity but my colleagues push sets me towards it

Comment: @Yukterez - Any more than 80 and I might not exist anymore. If there is a lot of empty space around the black hole and far away from it why would space be curved?

Comment: I think you are both saying the same thing then really. If the range of gravity is infinite there is no straight trajectory towards a black hole from any distance

Comment: Ok. If you want the BH gravity to be insignificant at your starting position, you need to be at a fairly large distance, unless it's a tiny BH. As far as we know, the smallest BHs that are formed from stars have a mass at least 2.5 times the Sun's mass, so the size of the region where their gravity is significant is larger than that of the Sun. It's *possible* that tiny BHs were formed in the very early universe, but searches have failed to find evidence fir them. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primordial_black_hole

Comment: You *can* have a straight trajectory to a BH. But if it's a stellar mass BH, and you're only a few days freefall time from it, then your space station is either orbiting the BH, or the station is using its engines to maintain its distance from the BH.

Comment: I’m curious why you think that if you were aimed at the black hole you might not fall straight toward it.